# Deploying Grafana as a FARGATE service in an AWS ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm having some issues with a Grafana deployment. After deploying Grafana, I cant change the default password for the admin account, which you have to do the first time you launch Grafana. I log in with the default credentials, then get prompted to enter a new password. When I do, I get an "unauthorized" error. Looking at the browsers console, it seems to give a 404 error when I try to submit a new password.

I'm using an RDS instance to store Grafana user data. The RDS instance is in the same subnet as the ECS cluster. I've attached the AmazonRDSDataFullAccess policy to the ECS task role but that did not help. I also tried making the RDS instance publicly available but that was also not helpful.

I'm using Grafana version 6.5.0. I was using the latest 7.1 but downgraded hoping it would solve my current issue.

Comment: What about SGs for the RDS? Do they allow SGs of the fargate tasks?

Comment: Yes. I've got inbound rules allowing access to port 3306 from the relevant subnets.

Comment: John, did you ever get this issues resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure your RDS database has a security group allowing inbound access from the ECS cluster. This will grant you the inbound access to the RDS database that are required.

As Fargate is serverless, a node could be destroyed so any local configuration would be gone. As you're using RDS you should make sure you're using [environment variables](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v4.4/installation/configuration/) to specify the DB connection details.

Finally add these to your task definition, using the [environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html) item. For secrets such as password for the RDS db use the [secrets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data.html) option.